# Sharing a Google Drive file without sending notification email

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-for-education

I am using Google Drive Java API. I need to copy a file from one Google domain to another, so my approach is the following:

1. authenticate with source domain service account
2. share file with user in destination domain
3. authenticate with destination domain service account and impersonate
   the user
4. copy the original file from origin domain to destination domain
5. delete the share permission from the original file

Everything works as expected except that I don't want the destination owner to receive the Google Drive email notifying him about the shared file. When the file is shared via the Web GUI one can disable the notification email so I guess this is also possible via the API, the question is how ^^ Anyone?

PS: I am open to new 'less tedious' methods to create a copy of a file from one domain to another if that is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On step 2, when sharing the file with the new user, you'll be using the [permissions.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) API call. You'll want to specify the `sendNotificationEmails=false` parameter along with this call to suppress the email notification.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 6):

In the [Google Drive API V3 with permissions.create()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) it has changed to singular: `sendNotificationEmail=false`

In a POST request it would be like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/*FILEID*/permissions?sendNotificationEmail=false
```