# Disable email notificaton when sharing a Google Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am using the Google Calendar API V3 to share Google calendars by managing the ACL Permissions. Many of my customers do not want an email notification when a new calendar is shared with them. Is there a way to disable that?

To explain bette what I am looking for: I also use the Google drive API v2 and that API addresses the issue by providing a sendNotificationEmails parameter that you can set to False when sharing a Google document (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071187/sharing-a-google-drive-file-without-sending-notification-email)). I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), you need to set `sendNotifications` to false so invitee didn't get the notification about the invitation even though invitee's calendar UI has New events setting to "true".

Check this [example](https://github.com/rosskarchner/govdelivery/blob/71fe7b80eec6b7e44fd84ac54555e9e351f279f9/govdelivery/xml_payloads.py).

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer but you are answering a different question namely: "How to disable notifications when I add a new event to a calendar"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible. Sharing a calendar involves adding an ACL for a given user/group, and the notification email is generated upon adding the ACL. There does not appear to be any way to suppress the notification email. Even if you could, if you are sharing with a group, the individual users must click a link to add the calendar to their Calendar app.

I have put in a [group of feature requests](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/bJFoHu37Mgs;context-place=forum/calendar) through the Calendar forum that would make this process easier. While it is aimed at the front end of the calendar application, I'm hoping they would add corresponding options to the APIs.