# Google Calendar API ACL roles

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have to create a website that has various calendar integrations. Which means the user grants access to the site admin to view/edit his primary calendar. So a real person -secretary- will do this. Not the computer via api calls.

I started off with google-calendar api and got it working w/o any problems.

But I got problems with [acl role options](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert#request-body). The docs states the `role` options is a string of either `none`, `freeBusyReader`, `reader`, `writer` or `owner`. Is it possible to create composite roles? I want `freeBusyReader` and `write access`.

Imagine the scenario a secretary checks the site member's shared primary calendar (via calendar.google.com) and can read all his calendar events. Instead i want to only show that to the secretary that this time of the day in the calendar is taken and you cannot place any events there. But still can place events to non occupied places in the calendar.

Comment: permissions in google Calendar are very limited unfortunately that's not something that its going to support directly.

Comment: @DaImTo i see. We also thinkered about using the `freeBusyReader` role. That way we can create an event and share it with the customer. The customer gets an email about the invitation and can accept it. The problem is, i cannot set notifications for the customer about the given event. The notifications will only be sent to the event creator and wont be inherited to the shared participants. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You may want to check the supported notification types for Google Calendar API. As stated, it is possible to send email notifications to attendees for events that were inserted or updated via API by setting the `sendNotifications` parameter in the insert/update request to true.

Comment: Additionally, the solution given in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943958/disable-email-notificaton-when-sharing-a-google-calendar) might also help wherein it also mentioned about a feature request filed [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/bJFoHu37Mgs;context-place=forum/calendar).